# Не срабатывает POST запрос

Tags: javascript, python

Есть два похожих post запроса. Первый работает адекватно. А второй-нет, не запускается функция на python. В чем проблема?

Первый запрос:

```
if(document.querySelector('li.logout')){
    document.querySelector('li.logout').onclick = function(){
        alert('работает');
        var form =  document.querySelector('main > form');
         form.method = 'post';
         form.action = '/logout';
         form.submit();
}
```

Функция на python

```
@app.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
def logout():
    login_status = logout_user()
    if login_status:
        trigger_logged_out()
        jsonify({'result': True})

        return redirect('/')
    return jsonify({'result': False})
```

Второй запрос:

```
if(document.getElementById('comeback_to_personal_account')){

    document.getElementById('comeback_to_personal_account').onclick = function(){  
        var form =  document.querySelector('main > form');
        alert('работает');
        form.method = 'post';
        form.action = '/comeback_to_personal_account';
        form.submit();
    }
}
```

Функция на python

```
@app.route('/comeback_to_personal_account', methods=['POST'])
def comeback_to_personal_account():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        data = get_default_user_data(current_user.get_id())
        return render_sidebar_template("personal_account.html", data=data)
```

Во втором запросе срабатывает alert, но API-нет. В чем проблема?

**EDIT 1**

В дебаг режиме четко видно, что не происходит вызов функции comeback_to_personal_account(), поэтому сделать аналог alert на серверной стороне нет возможности

Comment: попробуйте более специфичный для вашей проблемы заголовок использовать [ask]¶ Создайте *минимальный*, но *полный* пример кода, который демонстрирует проблему (к примеру, замените `comeback_to_personal_account()` на `return 'test'` [mcve] Опишите подробно, виден ли сетевой запрос на клиенте, что сервер отвечает (какой http статус).

Comment: Посмотрите консоль браузера. Сделайте аналог alert на сервере